# How to do datalist paging using linq to sql and datalist in asp 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, paging, datalist

I'm using datalist in my application and i'm binding datalist with lisq to sql

dim db=new linqdatacontext();
var products=from p in db.products select p;
datalist.datasource=products;
datalist.databind();

now how can i do paging in my datalist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keywords **Take** and **Skip**

```
var products=from p in db.products select p 
             Skip NUMER_TO_START Take NUMBER_TO_TAKE
```

Very simple, consider there are 1000 rows of results in p, and **Skip 50** means you are not going take results #1-#50, and it will give you results from #51, **Take** is simply how many records you need.