# I'm creating a page that uses Linqfor data access and I'm using DataList to display data. How can I use Linq to do data paging in asp.net using C#?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a page that uses Linqfor data access and I'm using DataList to display data.How can I use Linq to do data paging in asp.net?can anyone plz show both  the aspx part aspx.cs part?can anyone plz show both  the aspx part aspx.cs part?

Comment: what have you done? its better to show were are you stuck at rather than asking for code from the scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try searching on Google?

[How to do datalist paging using linq to sql and datalist in asp 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071812/how-to-do-datalist-paging-using-linq-to-sql-and-datalist-in-asp-3-5)

And here's an example that has markup and code-behind:

[DataList With LinQ Paging??](http://forums.asp.net/t/1376217.aspx)

Remember, Google is your friend:

[DataList DataPaging LINQ](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=1G1ACGW_ENUS358&q=DataList+DataPaging+LINQ&oq=DataList+DataPaging+LINQ&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=5051l10439l0l10699l24l19l0l7l1l0l242l1692l3.7.2l12l0)